# How to calculate ROC in ROCit?

Tags: r, roc

I wanted to use ROCit for creating ROC curves. Can I change the direction to compute the ROC curve
(the high values are related to health)?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  It's always good to include a minimal example ("[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)") if you can for us to work with, so for example when you say "high values are related *to health*" it will be more clear what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages("ROCit")
require(ROCit)
```

Since there's no example in the question, I'll start with an example from the docs of `?rocit` and please let me know if I've misinterpreted your question.

```
# Load some example data
data("Diabetes")

# Calculate some ROC/validation data
roc_empirical <- rocit(score = Diabetes$chol, class = Diabetes$dtest,
                       negref = "-") # default method empirical
roc_binormal <- rocit(score = Diabetes$chol, class = Diabetes$dtest,
                      negref = "-", method = "bin")

# Summarize and plot the results 
summary(roc_empirical) #60/329
summary(roc_binormal) 
plot(roc_empirical)
plot(roc_binormal, col = c("#00BA37", "#F8766D"),
     legend = FALSE, YIndex = FALSE)
```

We can look at the the output of `summary(roc_empirical)` for a baseline:

> ```
>  Empirical ROC curve                  
>  Number of postive responses :  60    
>  Number of negative responses :  329  
>  Area under curve :  0.652684903748734
> ```

Now, if I understand (?) you're just wanting to flip the meaning/direction of the reference value, which in this case is `Diabetes$dtest`?

We can use the `negref` argument to accomplish this:

```
roc_empirical <- rocit(score = Diabetes$chol, class = Diabetes$dtest,
                       negref = "+") # default method empirical
roc_binormal <- rocit(score = Diabetes$chol, class = Diabetes$dtest,
                      negref = "+", method = "bin")

summary(roc_empirical)
summary(roc_binormal) 
plot(roc_empirical)
plot(roc_binormal, col = c("#00BA37", "#F8766D"),
     legend = FALSE, YIndex = FALSE)
```

and we can compare the results of `summary(roc_empirical)` with what we had previously to see that it is "flipped":

> ```
>  Empirical ROC curve                  
>  Number of postive responses :  329   
>  Number of negative responses :  60   
>  Area under curve :  0.353850050658561
> ```

Of course, you could've also re-coded the column in question.

Is that all you needed?